# Building UDF on DB2

Tags: c, db2, user-defined-functions

what should i download and install in order to run User Defined Functions on DB2 ?

currently i've installed Control Center and I'm dealing with a problem finding ***sqludf.h*** & ***bldrtn*** files in order to write the suitable code in C.

I imagine the answer is really simple but i'm still a newbie in DB. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C headers, in Windows are under the DB2 installation folder. In my case is under:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\include
```

The other file is under

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\samples\c
```

In Linux/UNIX, the location should be similar

```
/opt/IBM/db2/V9.7/include
```

For more information about the header you are using:

Creating in c and c++ routines
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/t0020586.html

Description of sqludf.h
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0009056.html